# CSS Rotating Info Cards are Flickering

Tags: html, css

I have some pure HTML/CSS that I'm trying to figure out -

Hovering over the cards should perform a flip effect. The effect works, but if you run over it too quickly or at a weird angle it will create a sort of "stuttering". I'm trying to fix it so that it's seamless no matter what.

It seems like the issue happens when the cursor goes outside the card container, since the box is shrinking and expanding again to create that flip effect.

Any idea how to fix this?

https://codepen.io/mttmrn/pen/zgZKjj

```
HTML:

<body>

  <!-- 
            This is where the cards start
        -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-front">
        <img src="./img/cool-background.png" alt="background" class="card-img">
        <ul class="card-text">
          <li>React | Redux</li>
          <li>NodeJS</li>
          <li>JavaScript</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card-back">
        <ul class="card-text">
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>twice</li>
        </ul>
      </div>


CSS:

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background: rgb(250, 224, 30);
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 275px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-back {
  background: wheat;
}

.card-text {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px 50px 0px 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.card-text li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0004;
}

.card-img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 268px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 68%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 68%, 0 100%);
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.card-front:nth-child(1) {
  animation: fadeIn 1.5s 0.3s backwards;
}

.card-front:nth-child(2) {
  animation: fadeIn 1.5s 0.6s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(3) {
  animation: fadeIn 1.5s 0.9s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(4) {
  animation: fadeIn 2s 1.2s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(5) {
  animation: fadeIn 2s 1.5s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(6) {
  animation: fadeIn 2s 1.8s backwards;
}
```

The animation should be smooth when hovered over and should remain flipped until the cursor leaves the card.

Comment: There are many solutions available. First you can create a wrapper for a card and apply hover rules to it. Then on hover you rotate inner card,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for uploading the pen. I took a look for you and added an example on the following (reduced the clutter to just 1 card for example purposes):

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background: rgb(250, 224, 30);
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card {
  width: 275px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.box:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-front, .card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-back {
  background: wheat;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-text {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px 50px 0px 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.card-text li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0004;
}

.card-img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 268px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 68%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 68%, 0 100%);
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.card-front:nth-child(1) {
  animation: fadeIn 1.5s 0.3s backwards;
}

.card-front:nth-child(2) {
  animation: fadeIn 1.5s 0.6s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(3) {
  animation: fadeIn 1.5s 0.9s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(4) {
  animation: fadeIn 2s 1.2s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(5) {
  animation: fadeIn 2s 1.5s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(6) {
  animation: fadeIn 2s 1.8s backwards;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-7Gk1S6elg570RSJJxILsRiq8o0CO99g1zjfOISrqjFUCjxHDn3TmaWoWOqt6eswF" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <!-- 
            This is where the cards start
        -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="box">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-front">
        <img src="./img/cool-background.png" alt="background" class="card-img">
        <ul class="card-text">
          <li>React | Redux</li>
          <li>NodeJS</li>
          <li>JavaScript</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card-back">
        <ul class="card-text">
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>twice</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!--
            Card End
        -->
</body>

</html>
```

Essentially I've added a box wrapper and added the transform rules to that while cleaning up a little of the shared code on the front and back classes to avoid the card classes 'fighting' over the transform. I'd also take a look at the transform code and putting in some webkit bits too, ala:

```
transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform: ...
```

Let me know if there's anything you don't understand here or I can help you with further.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by moving your code pen to a StackSnippet. Use the `<>` button in the answer editor.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this is what you are looking for..
so all i had to do was adding a card-wrap div around each card div
and use hover on that card-wrap so that even when the actual card is rotating every thing going okay with the position of the cursor

```
.wrap-card:hover .card{
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

here's a snippet

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background: rgb(250, 224, 30);
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 12%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 275px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card-wrap:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-back {
  background: wheat;
}

.card-text {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px 50px 0px 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.card-text li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0004;
}

.card-img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 268px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 68%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 68%, 0 100%);
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.card-front:nth-child(1) {
  animation: fadeIn 1.5s 0.3s backwards;
}

.card-front:nth-child(2) {
  animation: fadeIn 1.5s 0.6s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(3) {
  animation: fadeIn 1.5s 0.9s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(4) {
  animation: fadeIn 2s 1.2s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(5) {
  animation: fadeIn 2s 1.5s backwards;
}
.card-front:nth-child(6) {
  animation: fadeIn 2s 1.8s backwards;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-7Gk1S6elg570RSJJxILsRiq8o0CO99g1zjfOISrqjFUCjxHDn3TmaWoWOqt6eswF" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <!-- 
            This is where the cards start
        -->
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card-wrap">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-front">
        <img src="./img/cool-background.png" alt="background" class="card-img">
        <ul class="card-text">
          <li>React | Redux</li>
          <li>NodeJS</li>
          <li>JavaScript</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card-back">
        <ul class="card-text">
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>twice</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-wrap">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-front">
        <img src="./img/cool-background.png" alt="background" class="card-img">
        <ul class="card-text">
          <li>React | Redux</li>
          <li>NodeJS</li>
          <li>JavaScript</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="card-back">
        <ul class="card-text">
          <li>hello</li>
          <li>twice</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 

  </div>
  <!--
            Card End
        -->
</body>

</html>
```